# How can I extract the structure of an operand with displacement in IDAPython?

Tags: ida, x86, idapython

Consider the following instruction:

`8D 8C 4E B0 2F FF FF  LEA    ECX, [ESI+ECX*2-0xD050]`

Using IDAPython, how can I extract the structure of the second operand? I'd like to know things like:

- `ESI` is the base register
- `ECX` is the index register
- `2` is the index constant
- `-0xD050` is the displacement constant

Its ok if I have to make a bunch of IDAPython API calls together. So far, I've had to resort to string parsing, and I'd really like to get rid of this.

---

The most relevant API function I've found is `idautils.DecodeInstruction()`, yet it doesn't seem to completely cover the structure of the second operand. See below for my exploration:

```
i = idautils.DecodeInstruction(<ea from above>)

# operand type
assert i.Op2.type == idc.o_disp

# operand value type
assert i.Op2.dtyp == idc.dt_dword

# operand flags
assert i.Op2.flags == idc.OF_SHOW

# structure of o_displ operand is like:
#
#    Memory Reg [Base Reg + Index Reg + Displacement].

def get_reg_const(reg):
    '''
    fetch register number from string name.
    '''
    ri = idaapi.reg_info_t()
    idaapi.parse_reg_name(reg, ri)
    return ri.reg

# we probably expect to find these constants in the operand structure
assert get_reg_const('ecx') == 1
assert get_reg_const('esi') == 6

# the operand structure
assert unsigned2signed(i.Op2.addr)  ==  0xD050  # displacement
assert i.Op2.n          == 1   # operand number
assert i.Op2.phrase     == 4   # "number of register phrase", don't know what this means
assert i.Op2.reg        == 4   # "number of register", don't see how this applies
assert i.Op2.specflag1  == 1   # unknown interpretation, could be "ecx"!?!
assert i.Op2.specflag2  == 78  # 0x4E, unknown interpretation
assert i.Op2.specflag3  == 0   # probably empty
assert i.Op2.specflag4  == 0   # probably empty
assert i.Op2.specval    == 0x200000  # unknown interpretation
assert i.Op2.value      == 0   # "outer displacement" (none here)
```

Comment: [This answer](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/9043/2959) to a similar question (although the question itself turned out to be a misunderstanding) suggests applying a regex to the entire string.

Comment: yeah, i would specifically like to avoid parsing string representations of the operands.

Comment: I found the following three API functions that might be relevant:
`get_op_tinfo2`, `get_operand_immvals`, `get_opinfo`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an elegant solution to this. Looks like if you would be writing a plugin in C you would be able to call `sib_base`, `sib_index`, `sib_scale` to get the info.

Here's how you could do it in Python.

```
from idautils import DecodeInstruction
from idaapi import get_reg_name

ea = 0x20AC5 # Assuming this ea is a lea
i = DecodeInstruction(ea)

hasSIB = i.Op2.specflag1
sib = i.Op2.specflag2

if hasSIB:
    base = sib  & 7
    index = (sib >> 3) & 7
    scale = (sib >> 6) & 3
    size = 4 if i.Op2.dtyp == idaapi.dt_dword else 8
    print '[{} + {}{} + {:x}]'.format(
        get_reg_name(base, size),
        get_reg_name(index, size),
        '*{}'.format(2**scale) if scale else '',
        i.Op2.addr
    )
```

Example Output:
`[ebx + eax*4 + 8c]`

Comment: this is just what i was looking for, thanks!